# Clerical Error (or rounding differences) In a UK Visa Application

Tags: visas, uk

I just submitted my UK tourist visa application and I inadvertently answered the question "The total amount of money you have for this trip" incorrectly. I answered 2000.36gbp, which should have been 2000gbp. At this moment I can't edit my application any more. What should I do?

Comment: Relax -- if your application is unsuccessful it won't be because of those 36 pence.

Comment: To be clear, you stated you had 2000.36 pounds, in stead of 2000 pounds?

Comment: yes i stated that the total amount i had for the trip is 2000.36 gbp instead of 2000gbp. like calculating all in the form was meant to add up to 2000gbp but i wrote 2000.36gbp

Comment: do i write a letter exxplaining that when submitting the form during my appointment

Answer (score 11):

You made an error on the visa application form and want to know how to handle it...

They like to think that errors fall in to several different categories.  Based upon what you wrote, your computation was off by 36p.  This falls in to the category of 'unintentional clerical error which would not affect the outcome'.

What that means is if the ECO saw the actual answer they would still make the same decision.  You can contrast this with a case where someone who had a criminal history answered 'NO' to that question.  That type of error can affect the outcome and so it is treated differently.

In a more general view, when I was doing applications for people, all the numbers were in whole units. Simple rounding is fine and ECO's are not going to be silly about trying to refuse somebody for rounding differences (doing so would violate the [Wednesbury Principle](http://en.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enwiki/310777/Wednesbury_unreasonableness) and they can get into serious trouble for doing that).

Had your error been significant or would have affected the outcome, then your recommended course is to cancel the application prior to submitting your biometrics.  But in the case you have described, it's not necessary to do anything.

Note: an alternative reference for the "Wednesbury Principle" as it occurs in English law can be examined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wednesbury_unreasonableness_in_Singapore_law#Development_and_application).  There is a pamphlet that describes how perversity fits in with the other grounds for judicial review [here](http://www.publiclawproject.org.uk/data/resources/113/PLP_2006_Guide_Grounds_JR.pdf).

Note: for an answer where the OP made a *significant* clerical error, see [Standard Visitor visa application in The Philippines submitted with error](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46209/uk-visa-in-the-philippines-submitted-with-clerical-error)

Comment: Do you have a better link for that? The page reloads every few seconds. Each time, the sidebar ad comes in a half second after the rest of the page, and causes the text to reflow, so the text is all but impossible to read. Futhermore, the constant reloading breaks the back button.

Comment: @TRiG, alternatively would you please try https://www.google.com/search?q=wednesbury+principle and select one of the offerings?

Comment: In Firefox, I just hit the "enter reader view" button (looks like an open book, immediately left of the reload button) and the page works fine.  It's a nice general-purpose "this page is broken" button.

Comment: @Kevin The page continuously reloads and that button disappears while the page is loading. I was unable to click it in five or six attempts.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: *shrug* It worked for me.  I had it reloading every few seconds, rather than continuously, so maybe it's just that I have faster internet and it can fully load before it reloads?

Comment: Answer updated with less volatile links.

Comment: @Kevin For me, the page was reloading more than once a second. Anyway, I'm sure reader mode will come in useful for other pages so thanks for the advice!