# Missing a Last Name on UK Visa Application

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, applications, indonesian-citizens

I am super worried that I missed a name on UK standard visitor visa application. On the passport it has first-second-last name but I missed out the last name. However, other identity cards such as a national identity card and birth certificate have only first-second name. The last name was added by the immigration officer later on. Will it be a big problem? If it will, does providing an application letter explaining will help? Otherwise, what should I do?

The the applicant is from Indonesia (categorised as a third country which has always been hard to obtain a visa). Also, the applicant has been granted a UK visa previously.

Comment: I’m not quite sure I understand - are you saying a UK official added your surname to the application when you attended your biometric appointment? If so, I doubt you have anything to be overly-concerned about; I would think that they would have rejected the application as ‘invalid’ (not a ‘refusal’). Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46209/standard-visitor-visa-application-in-the-philippines-submitted-with-error

Answer (score 3):

I am Indonesian myself and I understand that the names on our identity cards (which follow from birth certificates, near-impossible to change it legally) can be different to our passports, where family names often added here.

This is more common than people think, "family names" in Indonesia is a relatively new concept.

I suggest you write a cover letter explaining that. Maybe attach a copy of your KTP (national ID). Next time when you apply, you can write the first-second name under "any other names" instead, because the new form asks for your national identity card information.

You should always use whatever name is on your passport.

Answer (score 1):

As always when you notice something is in error or your circumstances has changed you should send the application for change to explain what happened and why.

With immigration and customs it is never a good idea to stick head in sand and hope they don’t notice because it will come back and haunt you at some point.

This is based on a personal experience where I accidentally washed my passport, got a temp one and tried to return to a country as a visitor without my previous visa as I thought they would never check and I was coming in on a visa waiver any way but low and behold of course they knew everything and I spent 6 hours explaining myself and was finally let in.

The TSA told me very calmly that had I just sent in the form about what happened this would have been a routine entry, nothing else - I just tripped myself.

So always assume you have to do the right thing.