# Wrong date to leave UK on application, will a cover letter with the correction help?

Tags: visas, uk, applications

I have made a mistake on the UK Visa application form (page 2) about my planned travel dates. I entered the incorrect date of when I will leave (October instead of November).

I have just wrote a correction letter which will go together with the supporting documents and I will indicate on the checklist that the correction  letter is there.

Is this a major issue, will it prevent the visa being issued, and will the correction letter help?

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46209/standard-visitor-visa-application-in-the-philippines-submitted-with-error

Comment: Hi, I've edited the question to make the real question clearer as well as clean up the grammar, please feel free to roll it back if you feel I have changed the intent of the question :)