# I just realized I forgot information on my visa application and I already had my Biometrics appointment (UK VISA)

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, applications

I applied for a tier 4 general student visa. Hours before my biometrics I realized I forgot to put down some countries I visited in Europe last year for travel history. My passport is stamped with these places, and I just completed my biometrics. If I cancel my application now to resubmit, will I have to redo my biometrics? Will this for sure get my visa rejected? UKVIS contact basically doesn't work and I have no answers for anything. My application support center said to call the UK embassy, but I have no idea what to do.

Comment: UK Embassies don't deal with visas. Applications are dealt with centraly in the UK. If you cancel now you will have to pay a new fee. Look if it possible to **append** an existing application. However I believe the 'point of no return' is the Biometric appointment for this.

Comment: @Meaghan S If you applied from outside the UK and have already given biometrics, your only option is to contact UKVI via phone or email to request to cancel the application https://www.gov.uk/cancel-visa Or let the application continue and hope for the best

Comment: @Traveller can he email them telling them he forgot to add that information? https://www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi-inside-outside-uk/y/outside-the-uk/english

Comment: @kiradotee He can try, but having completed biometrics the cut-off point for trying to amend any details is probably past. https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46209/standard-visitor-visa-application-in-the-philippines-submitted-with-error

Comment: Did you answer Yes or No to ""Have you travelled outside your country of residence, excluding to the UK, in the last 10 years?"